# Android-x86 on Virtualbox: eth0 network unavailable

Tags: virtualbox, android-x86

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to setup network on VirtualBox for Android 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257668/how-to-setup-network-on-virtualbox-for-android-2-3)

I'm trying to run android-x86-2.2-r2-eeepc.iso on VirtualBox. It's almost perfect, but I'm unable to set-up the network. The network adapters are not recognized, even if correctly configured in VirtualBox (I've other virtual machines, and they work just fine).

**Config:**

- VirtualBox 4.2.6
- android-x86-2.2-r2-eeepc.iso

**VirtualBox's network adapter config:**

- eth0 bridged network adapter (Intel Wifi Link 1000 BGN)

**When trying to set-up network inside android machine:**

```
# netcfg eth0 up
action 'up' failed (No such device)
# netcfg
lo        UP     127.0.0.1     255.0.0.0        0x0000000049
```

Comment: Didn't see that question. Solution for me was changing the network adapter de PC-Link III and type `netcfg eth0 dhcp`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you say other virtual machines, are they also Android ones?
This question seems similar to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069121/no-network-in-android-x86-on-virtualbox-4-1-2).

Comment: Nop, they are Ubuntu, MacOs, etc.