# No network in VirtualBox (Android)

Tags: android, emulation, virtualbox

I am unable to set up a network connection on my Android emulator using VirtualBox. I followed multiple posts that tell me to set the adapter to Bridged or NAT.

When I execute `netcfg` in the console while the Android is running, the following lines show:

```
lo      UP      127.0.0.1      255.0.0.0       0x0000049
eth0    UP      0.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         0x0001003
```

I need the left address from eth0 to use in Eclipse. Any tips how I can configure my internet?

edit:
It has to do that I'm using a wireless laptop. Are there any ways around to enable a faster emulator on Eclipse than the default one provided by Google?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the adapter to NAT you must set your network configuration to DHCP, but if you want set the adapter to Bridged set your network configuration manually according to your network.
Maybe isn't a network problem and it's a ISO image problem, check this question:
[How to set up network on VirtualBox for Android 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257668/how-to-setup-network-on-virtualbox-for-android-2-3)